# Can't find mongoose validation error within express error object

Tags: express, mongoose, axios

I'm using mongoose js and trying to insert a new document into a mongodb. I'm passing the data object to express using Axios. When I get a validation error, the express server identifies the problem very easily. It returns an error `productCode: ValidatorError: Path 'productCode' is required.`

The error that is returned to express is a huge object and I can't find the validation error in it. Can someone tell me what I'm missing in my catch error?

**UPDATED**

Path: `Express axios Post catch error`

```
const product = {
  productCode: '1a',
  productName: 'product x'
};

async function createProduct(product) {
  axios
    .post(
      `http://localhost:3000/myroute`,
      product
    )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('res', res.data.productCode);
      return res.data.productCode;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // console.log('err', err.response);

      if (error.response) {
        /*
         * The request was made and the server responded with a
         * status code that falls out of the range of 2xx
         */
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        /*
         * The request was made but no response was received, `error.request`
         * is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance
         * of http.ClientRequest in Node.js
         */
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request and triggered an Error
        console.log('Error', error.message);
      }
      // console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Path: `Server`

```
const product = new Product(req.body);

product
  .save()
  .then((result) => {
    res.status(200).json(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('err', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.reason });
  });
```

Path: `Model`

```
var productSchema = new Schema(
  {
    productCode: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    productName: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
  { collection: 'products', timestamps: true, versionKey: false }
);
```

Comment: Can you include the entire axios promise in your question, including the request body object you are sending to the server

Comment: @rantao Updated. Is this what you wanted

Comment: Hmm it looks like your passing your request object correctly; You'll have to take a look at your controller or wherever you're saving the request body to the db, and make sure that the model is receiving the `productCode` property, since it's flagging that its required and is not receiving it. If you update your question again to include where you're making the save op, I can take a look as well

Comment: By the way the root of your problem is not in the .catch block, its coming from wherever you're handling the data in your API. The `catch` is simply returning the error

Comment: @rantao updated again. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`
or `app.use(express.json())` in your `app.js`?

Comment: I'm using app.use(express.json())